# Setting up PyCharm CE 4 to work with PyQGIS library in Mac OS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, mac, pycharm

I am trying to set up PyCharm to work with PyQGIS library. I am using PyCharm CE v4 and QGIS version 2.8 I have tried to implement the instructions of several posts like:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/PyQGIS-API-code-completion-not-working-in-PyCharm-td5082591.html or

http://inasafe.org/en/developer-docs/platform_osx.html#pycharm-setup

but I did not get any positive result. Any clue about the solution?